# Show picked photo in a dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am creating a dialog programmatically in an Activity. The dialog has a custom View which is also created programmatically. This custom View includes a TextView and an ImageView. By default, the TextView is shown and the ImageView is hidden. When the TextView is clicked i call an Intent to choose a photo from the gallery or from Camera. When the photo gets chosen i want the TextView to be hidden and The ImageView to be shown with  this chosen photo.

So how can i do this ?

```
dialog.setTitle("Complete task informations");
                        // The container layout inside of the dialog
                        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
                        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.addView(pickIcon);
                        // The chosen icon
                        CircleImageView pickedIconDia = new CircleImageView(MyActivity.this);
                        pickedIconDia.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        layout.addView(pickedIcon);
                        // The listener to click event on both icon (to change) and its chooser (to pick)
                        View.OnClickListener pickIconListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                pickIcon(pickedIconDia);
                                if(taskIconPath != null){
                                    pickIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    pickedIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        // Releying the listener to the two widgets
                        pickIcon.setOnClickListener(pickIconListener);
                        pickedIcon.setOnClickListener(pickIconListener)
```

I do not know how to set the photo to the ImageView from onActivityResult. 
I know there are Event managements that can listen to such Events but i did not find appropriate one.

I have tried Eventbus but it did not work.

So, how is this possible ?

**Additional Code**

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                //
                Picasso.with(this).load(taskIconPath).into(myView);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.some_error_occured), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show complete code to understand your logic and flow

Comment: Thank you @androidXP for your response. Please check the answer, i updated it with additional code

Comment: `Picasso.with(this).load(taskIconPath).into(myView);`. We do not see myView at other places in your code. Please add relevant code. But..... What is `taskIconPath`? You are not using the choosen image at all.

Comment: And Picasso will load an image from the uri data.getData(). You can directly use the uri.

Comment: @greenapps, `taskIconPath` and `myView` are both non static  fields inside the activity class. I used them just to test if i the ImageView can be accessed by reference inside the onActivityResult but this did not work

Comment: Ok, i can use the uri with Picasso but the question is WHERE TO LOAD THIS URI ? WHERE IS MY IMAGEVIEW IN THAT MOMENT ??

Comment: Your image view will be in the dialog as you said. Why do you ask us? YOU should know where it is!

Comment: Ok, i know it is inside the dialog but i meant how to acccess it from onActivityResult?